# How to click div element to show hidden data with selenium or BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I have to scrape data from a page which described bottom, my goal is to get phone number which described in the blue square on the left bottom , but the phone number is not quite visible, it will be shown fully only after clicking at.

I tested by Selenium, but no result, it returns `NoSuchElementException` error

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

s = Service('home/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
driver.get("https://bina.az/items/3141057")
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"show-phones js-show-phones active")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues here:

1. The element you trying to click is out of the visible screen. SO, you first need to scroll the screen in order to access it.
2. `show-phones` `js-show-phones` `active` are **3** class names. If you want to use all these 3 values you should use `CSS_SELECTOR` instead of `CLASS_NAME` but since `show-phones` is enough to make unique locator you can use it alone with `CLASS_NAME`.
3. Instead of hardcoded sleeps `time.sleep(5)` `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits should be used.

The following code works:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
actions = ActionChains(driver)

url = "https://bina.az/items/3141057"
driver.get(url)



element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "show-phones")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
time.sleep(0.5)
element.click()
```

The result is

[image]